# how to filter a list based on each item data attribute

Tags: jquery, filter, html-lists

Trying to filter a list like this:

```js
$('.show-fields').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.subList').hide();
       var filter= $(this).data('filtro'); //the value i want to filter the list by
       $('.fieldsList').not(':data(tipo)').hide();
       $('.subList').show();
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bs-glyphicons-list">
                                    <li class="show-fields" data-filtro="tutti" data-html="true" title="Visualizza <b>tutti i campi</b>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Tutti</span></li>
                                    <li class="show-fields" data-filtro="input" data-html="true" title="Campi basati su template <b>input</b>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Input</span></li>
                                    <li class="show-fields" data-filtro="textarea" data-html="true" title="Campi su template <b>testo libero</b>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Testo libero</span></li>
                                    <li class="show-fields" data-filtro="opzioni" data-html="true" title="Campi su template <b>opzioni</b>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Opzioni</span></li>
                                    <li class="show-fields" data-filtro="validato" data-html="true" title="Campi su template <b>input validati</b>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Input validati</span></li>
                                    <li data-html="true" title="Aggiungi un campo" data-toggle="modal" id="addField"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Aggiungi un campo</span></li>
                                </ul>


<ul class="bs-glyphicons-list">
       <li class="fieldsList" data-tipo="input" data-value="nome" data-description="Nome: Un campo testo di massimo 256 caratteri" id="fields_nome"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Nome</span></li>
       <li class="fieldsList" data-tipo="input" data-value="cognome" data-description="Cognome: Un campo testo di massimo 256 caratteri" id="fields_cognome"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Cognome</span></li>
       <li class="fieldsList" data-tipo="validato" data-value="mail" data-description="Mail: Un campo testo di massimo 256 caratteri" id="fields_mail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Mail</span></li>
        <li class="fieldsList" data-tipo="validato" data-value="telefono" data-description="Telefono: Un campo testo di massimo 256 caratteri senza formato specifico" id="fields_telefono"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Telefono</span></li>
        <li class="fieldsList" data-tipo="validato" data-value="codice-fiscale" data-description="Codice fiscale: Un campo testo in formato codice fiscale italiano" id="fields_codice-fiscale"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Codice fiscale</span></li>
        <li class="fieldsList" data-tipo="validato" data-value="data" data-description="Data: Un campo data generico in formato gg/mm/aaaa" id="fields_data"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Data</span></li>
        <li class="fieldsList" data-tipo="validato" data-value="ora" data-description="Ora: Un campo ora generico in formato hh:mm" id="fields_ora"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span><span class="glyphicon-class">Ora</span></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to filter it based on each li data-tipo attribute value. 
The code I am trying is in the snippet

what I don't understand is how to pass to `.not` the filter value. I know that `:data(tipo)` is not correct. What should I put here?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: @Taplar coming from that page and from similar questions on SO too. But missing the bit to apply it here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what confuses you?  `data-tipo` is an attribute.  You just need to make an attribute selector.

Comment: so it's just .not('data-tipo='+filter) ? so simple?

Comment: What does the api say, about how to make an equals check against an attribute?

Comment: Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”] Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value. But I get Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "data-tipo"="input" this way.

Comment: Look at the examples in that api page.  How do they differ from what you are attempting?

Comment: got it... .not('li[data-tipo=filter]') thanks @Taplar, I was looking at the solution without seeing it :-)

Comment: Yep, no problem.  Definitely when you have questions like this, make sure to refer to the api and try to search related to the methods you are trying to use/do.  And pay close attention to the examples as they can be very useful if you are confused by the technical specs.  Edit: Not saying that this will solve your whole problem, but I did want to address your `:data(tipo)` question, specifically.